# having a hard time on 403 GET MESSAGE in vscdoe jupyer notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I ran the jupyter notebook server in the AWS-EC2 environment and remotely accessed the jupyter notebook from the local pc with vscode. Notebook works fine. The problem is that even if the connection is terminated, these log messages keep coming from the ec2 jupyter server.

```
[W 00:05:36.212 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1677888334886 (my-IP) 3.060000ms referer=None
[W 00:05:36.212 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 00:05:36.212 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1677888334885 (my-IP) 3.190000ms referer=None
[W 00:05:36.212 NotebookApp] Forbidden
```

I've done a lot of searching, tried shutting down http-proxy or deleting all jupyter runtime files, but I could still see these messages. The only solution was to delete and reload the jupyter extension from vscode. A jupyter notebook in a browser environment has a stable method called "logout". Is there such a thing in vsCode?

Comment: Again, when I install the jumpyter extension, I can see these messages without fail.

Comment: I see it running locally, and it shows a notebook I've never used.  :|   It shows it every 5-10 seconds.